# Find a substring in a String returns -1 although substring is available

Tags: c++, string

I have again a strage C++ thing on the following:

**l** is an incomming line (string.c_str()) **> becomes line**
**pos** is the position from where to start searching
**s** is a string (string.c_str()) to look for **> becomes command**

It all works fine until **command** is "-1". In this case the string "-1" is not found although line is containing it.
Am I missing something ovious?

**Code:**

```
bool Converter::commandAvailable(const char* l, int pos, const char* s) {

string line = l;
string command = s;
int x = line.find(command, pos);
if (x != -1) {
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain that the `const char* l` that you pass in, definitely points to some data with "-1" in it? Since you are passing in `const char*` for `l`, I'm wondering if you're not accidentally advancing that pointer beyond your "-1", perhaps elsewhere in your code before you pass it to your function?

Comment: std::string::find returns a size_t, which you should compare to std::string::npos

Comment: Your parameters are going to be wrong, print them out at the top of the function so you can see what is going on.

Comment: Also, no reason to construct a string "command" from "s". Just rename the const char* "s" to "command".

Comment: I already was looking at with with watches while debugging... the values are comming correctly... I constructed "command" out of "s" for testing purpose and to find the issue.

Comment: Your code works it seems. I posted it in [codepad](http://codepad.org/3GqRaN0k) and it works well

Comment: ok i just could track down the issue... I don't exactly know why but on this "item" something funny happened to the pos which is given to this method. That means it wasn't really a big deal. Thank you all anyway! I really appreciate the help of this community! :) I'll pick the answer below as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you find the problem:

```
bool Converter::commandAvailable(const char* l, int pos, const char* s) 
{
    string line = l;
    string command = s;
    std::cout << "INPUT" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LINE:  " << line << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CMD:   " << command << std::endl;
    std::cout << "START:  " << pos << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::size_t x = line.find(command, pos);

    std::cout << "OUTPUT:  " << x << std::endl;
    if (x != std::string::npos) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am actually watching the values with watches in eclipse. I thing it's equals to print them isn't it?